# fold a list of lists to produce a list

Tags: python, list

So I've got the following list:

```
cd = [[0.1,0.2,0.1,0.9], [0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.1],[0.2,0.3,0.1,0.5]
```

and I'd like to get the product of the individual elements of the nested lists in a list format...

so I'm going for:

```
p = [(0.1*0.2*0.2),(0.2*0.3*0.3),(0.1*0.4*0.1),(0.9*0.1*0.5)]
```

**note that this isn't a 1 to 1 relationship between cd and p.**

I'd like to do it simply...

In F#, for example, I would just do list.fold, and use a list as my accumulator.  Is there a python equivalent, or do I have to do:

```
p = [cd[0]]
if len(cd) > 1:
    for i in range(len(cd) - 1):
        for j in range(len(p)):
            p[j] = p[j]*cd[i+1][j]
return p
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

```
[reduce(lambda a, b: a*b, x)  for x in zip(*cd)]
```

This should work for multiple lists, and doesn't require any imports.

As @DSM mentions, you would also have to "import functools" and use "functools.reduce" for python3.

Comment: nice! thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Note that you have to import reduce from itertools when using Python3.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using a list comprehension.

```
cd = [[0.1,0.2,0.1,0.9], [0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.1]]
print [i*j for i,j in zip(cd[0],cd[1])]
```

If you want only 2 decimal places.

```
print [round(i*j,2) for i,j in zip(cd[0],cd[1])]
```

If you have multiple strings use

```
cd = [[0.1,0.2,0.1,0.9], [0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.1],[1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0]]
from operator import mul
print [reduce(mul, i, 1) for i in zip(*cd)]
```

Comment: `zip(*cd)` is a tad more concise

Comment: Nice (although not for the first time this sort of thing makes me wonder why the "batteries included" Python doesn't have a `product` function to go with its `sum` function).

Answer (score 3):

You can combine `reduce` with `zip` (and we could use a lambda here for multiplication, but since we're importing anyway, we might as well use `mul`):

```
>>> from operator import mul
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> cd = [[0.1,0.2,0.1,0.9], [0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.1],[0.2,0.3,0.1,0.5]]
>>> [reduce(mul, ops) for ops in zip(*cd)]
[0.004000000000000001, 0.018, 0.004000000000000001, 0.045000000000000005]
```

(Python 3; you don't need to import `reduce` if you're using an outdated Python.)

Comment: TIL `map` can also be used similar to zip: `map(lambda *y: reduce(mul, y), *cd)`

Comment: I would accept this one for the use of `operator.mul` :)

Answer (score 0):

You have a general solution with Numpy, working with more than two sublists:

```
import numpy as np
cd = [[0.1,0.2,0.1,0.9], [0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.1]]
out = np.apply_along_axis(np.prod, 0, cd)
```

Comment: yeah...oh well.  limited in the libraries I can use. I'll remember that for the future though, and mark this as answered in a bit

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
out = [ reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, z) for z in zip(*cd) ]
```